# Removing wall in basement

Tags: walls, removal

I wanted to take this wall down in my basement but wanted to know if I can take all of the 2x8s out or if I needed a lally column or 2 or if I can double up 2 of the 2x8s in the middle? Not sure if you’ll even be able to tell from pictures but figured I’d ask

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaUtb.jpg)

[image][image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It does look like a load bearing wall, so need for for an engineer/building inspector is called for.  Replacing the studs with some support/lally posts should be possible, but placement will be up to the engineer.  We cannot tell if any or all of the studs are used for support or just to make the drywall look good.  Removing the wrong one/s could be messy and painful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can only safely be answered by a structural engineer, no matter how helpful a bunch of random people on the internet want to be. We're certainly not going to be liable should something go wrong, and a lack of SE approved paperwork could be grounds for an insurance company to deny a claim should something go wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It does look like a load bearing wall, so would recommend for an engineer/building inspector advice.

Randomly replacing the studs with some support posts is not advised but placement will be up to the engineer.

Not following a professional advice could lead to severe problems.